# AT commands with Android

Tags: android, gsm, at-command, ril

I am trying to pass an authentication key to the sim card in order to return the response of sim internal algorithms related to gsm authentication but i could not find a way to do that. Is there a way to execute AT commands to a non-rooted phone in my android application ?